# Is there a c#/asp.net mvc3 file image picker/uploader control for Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image-uploading, azure-blob-storage

Before I reinvent any wheels, has anyone seen a file uploader/image browser control (you know, the kind of thing typical in a CMS) that works with Azure Blob storage? The stuff I've used to date relies on physical directory structures.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no image uploader control for ASP.NET MVC.
You should use   tag for uploading image.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [Aurigma Image Uploader](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/) worked for us in an MVC3 project. Take the uploaded file bytes and shove them in Azure File Storage.

We use [Azure File Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to manage files in file Azure File Storage.

Comment: will that cater for browsing and selecting from the Azure storage too ?

Comment: To display uploaded images we create a mapping in our database to those Azure file blob locations. To manage files (when we have problems) we use the Azure File Storage Manager mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, we use [PlUpload](http://www.plupload.com/), and it works pretty good with the blobs.

Comment: that covers the client end of the upload side, but not an image picker. I'm really looking for the two together.